# Python v.3 add single elements into list

Tags: python, list

Program takes a phone number and adds single digits to list

This is my input `867-5309`

This is my **desired** output `[8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]`

This is what I get *instead* `[[8, 6, 7], [5, 3, 0, 9]]`

How to fix???

```
import re
import num2words

pattern=[r'\d+']
ph=[]

phone = input("Enter phone number ")
print("You entered: ", phone)

for p in pattern:
    match=re.findall(p,phone)
    #print(match)

for i in range(len(match)):
    n=match[i]
    ph.append([int(d) for d in str(n)])
    #print(num2words.num2words(match[i]))

print(ph)
```

*Ultimately I wish the program to take the digits and spell out each digit (but that is a different thread, if necessary), i.e 867-5309, `eight six seven five three zero nine`*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going way to complicated here.

First of all your regex is greedy which means its matching all numbers up to - and then all other after as one match.

You can do this with a less greedy regex and then the match turns into exactly your desired output.

See code below.

```
import re

phone = input("Enter phone number ")
print("You entered: ", phone)


match = re.findall('\d', phone)
print(match)
```

Output is,

```
['8', '6', '7', '5', '3', '0', '9']
```

from there you can do this.

```
for i in match:
    print(num2words.num2words(i))
```

which outputs,

```
eight point zero
six point zero
seven point zero
five point zero
three point zero
zero point zero
nine point zero
```

only thing left is to get rid of the "point zero", I'm not familiar with num2words I'm afraid.

Comment: try `print(num2words.num2words(int(i)))`

Answer (score 2):

why not just something like this:

```
ph_str = '867-5309'
ph_list = [int(i) for i in ph_str if i.isnumeric()]
print(ph_list)  # [8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]
```

[str.isnumeric](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isnum#str.isnumeric) checks if the digit (as string) can be converted to an `int`. the rest is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?list-comprehensions#list-comprehensions) that directly generates the list you are looking for.

Comment: Just beat me to the same answer... my only addition would be to suggest the `inflect` module (https://pypi.org/project/inflect/) for doing numbers to words.

Answer (score 0):

This might also work:

```
number = "867-5309"
lst = []

for i in number:
    if i in "0123456789":
        lst.append(int(i)) 

print(lst) # [8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Other one liner option:

```
[ int(n) for m in s.split('-') for n in m  ]
```